# How to get the input text value in jquery from handlebar page when user enters data in input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I have this input field with select dropdown defined in handlebar file.

```
  <select name="assigneeSelect" id="{{this.commonID}}" class="custom-select sources" key="{{this.id}}" placeholder="{{this.assignee}}">
    <option value="5f572f2f68b4420488b585cb">Charlotte Miles</option>
    <option value="5f4d494c6dba221200f2cc1e">Sulekha Yadav</option>
    <option value="5f4d49636dba221200f2cc1f">Adele Armstrong</option>
  </select>

<input class="form-control" class="deadline" type="text"  value="{{this.deadline}}"/>
```

Here is the UI. Both are in one row in different `<td>`

[image]

First I fill the deadline input text with some data and then I change the select drop-down option. So now what I want is that onChange of select dropdown i want to fetch the respective row's input text and then I need to send it via AJAX call on nodejs server side  which then update the deadline field in backend mongoDB which gets reflected back in deadline input field again when the page loads.

I am trying this code for fetching its value but isn't working.

```
var deadline = $(".deadline").text();
alert(deadline);
```

Here I am getting blank alert. Also I am fetching data with class attribute because there are similar many rows on same page.

Answer (score 0):

use val() function   like this

```
         var deadline = $(".deadline").val();
          alert(deadline);
```

Comment: the alert dailoag Appears or not

Comment: or use this in head of html            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>